# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.app-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator

In my Project, I have a deployment target of iOS 6.  I want to test my app in the iOS 6.1 Simulator, but Xcode 6.1 does not support iOS Simulators older than iOS 7.0, so I have downloaded and installed Xcode 5.1.1.  When I build the app in Xcode 5.1.1, it gives me this error:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.app-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
```

How can I fix the problem and run the app in the iOS 6 Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to copy the simulator folder from an older version of Xcode into your new version, or at least it was in previous builds of Xcode. I found a description of how to do this here on SO and did it with Xcode 5 and a previous SDK. It should work with Xcode 6.1.

I don't have ready access to the info any more I'm afraid.

I suggest searching for "install iOS 6 simulator in Xcode".

Edit: According to Jeremy, Apple changed the format of the simulator in Xcode 6, so this won't work between Xcode 4/5 and Xcode 6.

Comment: iOS 6.0 and 6.1 are not compatible with CoreSimulator which is the new simulator architecture in Xcode 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

App Extensions require iOS 8.0 and later.  If you want to test your project in iOS 6.1 with Xcode 5.1, you should just remove the App Extension target from your project when testing in Xcode 5.1 as it's not applicable to the old OS version.